# AutoMapper returnning empty and null

Tags: c#, automapper, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Mapping a Dto to a Model per below - on mapping = a completely empty model!

There are a mix of nullable and non-nullable references in both objects.

**The Model**

```
    public class TheModel
    {
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }
        public Guid Type { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } = null!
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? ItIsAnything { get; set; }
    
        public string Internal { get; set; } = null!; 
        public string? AnotherInternal { get; set; }
    }
```

**The Dto**

```
    public class TheDto
    {
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }
        public Guid Type { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; } //  is nullable in the dto
        public string Description { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? ItIsAnything { get; set; }
    }
```

**The Map and execution - Dto to Model**

```
    CreateMap<TheDto, TheModel>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.Id ?? Guid.Empty))
    
    // attempt for non-nullable references in Model that are nullable in Dto
    
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Internal , opt => opt.NullSubstitute("")); 
    
    // execute
    var dto = new TheDto{
        Id = null,
        Type = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Title = null;
        Description = "any desc";
    }
    
    var model = _mapper.Map<TheModel>(dto);
    
    ///// model is all empty !
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set up [works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ZNxjD) except [`NullSubstitute`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Null-substitution.html) for Internal. It will substitute if the source value is null anywhere along the member chain, but you have no `Internal` on the source. You can do something like this for example:

```
.AfterMap((dto, model) => model.Internal ??= "NotNull");
```

P.S.

for `Id` `NullSubstitute` works (`.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.NullSubstitute(Guid.Empty))`)

Comment: Thanks - you are right, my setup is fine = I realized the problem was in model-binding not mapping - I am withdrawing question - thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem was in model-binding not mapping